# Variable expansion including spaces within alias definition

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here. I have the following code in my .bashrc and .zshrc for reasons not relevant to the question (but I can explain the reason why if needed, not a secret, just not relevant):

```
export LS_OPTIONS="-lAhF --color=auto --group-directories-first --time-style=+%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

When I run the `ls` alias I got the following error:

```
ls: cannot access '%H:%M:%S': No such file or directory
```

Obviously the alias is not keeping the backslash in the middle of the `--time-style` option. And obviously I've tried like a ton of different quoting styles to keep the backslash or the space there, to no avail.

To make things worse, the solution has to work in **both** Zsh and Bash, so no tricky parameter expansions I can use.

It's been years since I was really proficient with shell scripting so I've forgotten all the hairy tricks, but I have the feeling I'm missing the obvious solution here.

Thanks in advance and while I wait for a reply I'll keep trying different quotation mechanisms to see if I find the solution myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting your options in array instead :

```
export LS_OPTIONS=( -lAhF --color=auto --group-directories-first --time-style=+%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)
```

then use it as :

```
alias ls='ls "${LS_OPTIONS[@]}"'
```

Comment: Thanks @funkyjelly. I already saw that suggestion in this other stackoverflow [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), but I was not sure if this will work the same in Zsh. Turns out it will (or so it seems...) so I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

use " instead of '

```
export LS_OPTIONS="-lAhF --color=auto --group-directories-first --time-style=+%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S"
alias ls="ls $LS_OPTIONS"
```

variable expansion only works with "

Comment: Yes, but an alias is expanded again when it is used, so single quoting an alias is fine.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Not in this case. With single-quotes, the `$LS_OPTIONS` part isn't expanded until the alias is used, so the options variable is subject to word splitting but escapes aren't parsed, causing the original problem. With double-quotes, the variable is expanded when the alias is *defined*, so when it gets parsed the escape is already there and gets properly parsed. Net result: it works when you use double-quotes. On the other hand, if you have to work this hard to understand *why* it works, you should probably find a better way to do it.

Comment: UtLox, thanks for the solution :) @gordon-davisson the problem with this solution (which I tried when testing various quotings) is that I'd like for the variable to be expanded when the alias is used so if it has changed the new value is used without having to redefine the alias. Other than that, it's a viable solution.